# What is the new battery/gear/hammer icon all about?

Tags: galaxy-attack-alien-shooter

With the recent update a new icon that displays an icon displays an ABI item like battery and 0/10 appears in single player upper right corner. What is this icon all about?

How do i get the batteries, hammers etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While playing any single player game (campaign endless or boss) from time to time the enemies will drop a batteries. Pick them up and you will increase the number of batteries. After collecting all the batteries 20/20 you will be able to receive a reward (a ticket and money)

You can then use the tickets (its 20 tickets for first drone) and money to buy a galactic drone. In the upgrade menu

Galactic drones drop as upgrades just like regular ships do but have a limited time that they last.